# Custom WP_QUERY $args

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have an SQL query here:

```
$data_listg = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts where post_type='post' and SUBSTR(" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts.post_title, 1, 1) LIKE '%$data' and post_status='publish' LIMIT 2" );
```

The query shows posts by first word. For example:

If titles start with "A" or "B" then show that post first.

- American hair style
- A new Audi
- Amazing cars
- Alphabet

or  "B"

- B

The problem is when to change:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args  = array(
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 2
);
```

How do I add that into my WP_Query `$args`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom filters in `$args` (not tested)

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'find_by_title_filter', 10, 2 );
function find_by_title_filter( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $find_title_arg = $wp_query->get( 'find_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $find_title_arg ) ) . '';
    }
    return $where;
}

$custom_var = 'a';

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
         $args = array(
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'find_title'     => $custom_var
            );
```

Comment: ohh i see, but not working, okey i want explore your code

Answer (score 1):

yess SOLVED i modified

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'find_by_title_filter', 10, 2 );
function find_by_title_filter( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $find_title_arg = $wp_query->get( 'find_title' ) ) {
        $where .= " AND SUBSTR(" . $wpdb->posts . ".post_title,1,1) LIKE '%$find_title_arg%' ";
    }
    return $where;
}
```